# Building SDL2_image alongside SDL2 (and similar cases)

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2

I have the following conditions:

1. I am using SDL2 (sources) as dependency directly from github mirror by using git submodules
2. Also i am using SDL2_image (sources) as similar dependency
3. My cmake project includes both deps with `add_subdirectory`

Problem here is that SDL2_image is trying to find SDL2 with `find_package`, but as i mentioned i am building SDL2 alongside with my project, so `find_package` fails to find it in the system. After that i am setting SDL2_DIR pointing to the correct directory, but [SDL2Config.cmake](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/master/SDL2Config.cmake) inside one of the most popular unofficial repos are just including invalid file and thus breaks all project.

Question is. How i can nicely solve this issue? I have all my deps built from sources alongside the project and it works nice. Of course i can build SDL2_image and include binaries separately, but this is not a nice solution in my opinion.

Comment: Which repo (and CMake file) did you use for SDL2_Image? It might as easy as shipping your own FindSDL2.cmake that links to the SDL2 target you're building.

Comment: I am using this repo https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL_image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `FindSDL2.cmake` with the following:

```
add_library(SDL2::SDL2 ALIAS SDL2)
```

Make sure `find_package` sees this file first by adding the path to it to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` or `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.